# PHP syntax using ?and :

Tags: php, syntax

So, this works:

```
<?php
 $value = ($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : $y[0];
 $output = '<input type="text" name="field1" value="'.$value.'">';
?>
```

But how to make it work in this case:

```
 <?php
  $output = '<input type="text" name="field1" value="'.$($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : $y[0];.'">';  
?>
```

Comment: Reducing the number of lines of code in a program can be a virtue, in this case it is the opposite. You are reducing the readability (and thus maintainability) of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the first dollar, that does not belong there, wrap it into braces and remove the semicolon:

```
$output = '<input type="text" name="field1" value="'.(($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : $y[0]).'">';
```

Comment: Thank you! This first dollar was a typo. But adding extra brackets - never thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

No semicolon:

```
value="' . ($_POST['x'] ? $_POST['x'] : $y[0]) .'">';
```

I also get the feeling you want to use `isset($_POST['x'])`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="type" value="<?php echo $condition ? $variant1 : $variant2 ?>" />
```

Comment: Please think about adding a comment to your "code only" answer.

Comment: "Talk is cheap. Show me the code." - Linus Torvalds. What is not clear in one line of the code?

Comment: To be specific: He doesn't get the idea of ternary operators, so giving him another example of code is just a meta answer and does not help him with his problem. Since you are new to stackoverflow (or this is one of your first contributions) check out this very helpful answer on meta (especially no. 10): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer